# having trouble installing canopy 1.7.2 on my ubutu 12.04 amd64 computer

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, canopy

I am having trouble installing the canopy installer 1.7.2 on my Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 computer. I have downloaded the software in the "downloads" folder but I get the following error:

```
$ bash canopy-1.7.2-rh5-64.sh
No such file or directory
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

When you open a terminal, you are in your home directory: `$HOME`. The Downloads folder is a subdirectory of your `$HOME`, so it's `$HOME/Downloads`. Therefore, to run a script in that directory you need to either:

1. Move into that directory first and then run it:

   ```
   cd Downloads
   bash canopy-1.7.2-rh5-64.sh
   ```
2. Use the full path

   ```
   bash Downloads/canopy-1.7.2-rh5-64.sh
   ```